# In C# how to create a List<T> with a default count of zero?

Tags: c#

Rookie question:

I have been experiencing a minor bug in my mvc2 application. I was able to trace it back to this code:

```
List<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes = new List<Stream2FieldTypes>();
foreach (var item in stream.Stream2FieldTypes) 
{ 
   Stream2FieldTypes.Add(item); 
}
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I instatiate the new list, it has a count of one. I'm thinking that this is probably due to my using the constructor. So I tried this:

```
List<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes;
foreach (var item in stream.Stream2FieldTypes) 
{ 
   Stream2FieldTypes.Add(item); 
}
```

But, of course this will not compile because of an error on `Stream2FieldTypes.Add(item);`. Is there a way that I can create a `List<Stream2FieldTypes>` and make sure that the count is zero?

Comment: The default length of a List is zero, not one - do you have any more code to post?

Comment: There's no `Length` property on `List<T>`. Could you clarify if you are talking about `Count` or `Capacity`? Fyi, the default value of `Count` is `0` .

Comment: Sorry... I meant `count()`. I edited the question.

Comment: How are you checking the count to arrive at the conclusion that the list has 1 item?

Comment: I had inserted a breakpoint. But I was looking in the wrong area. @Darin's answer correctly pointed out my error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The problem that I am experiencing is that when I instatiate the new list, it has a length of one

No, that's totally impossible. Your problem is somewhere else and unrelated to the number of elements of a newly instantiated list.

```
List<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes = new List<Stream2FieldTypes>();
```

`Stream2FieldTypes.Count` will be 0 at this point no matter what you do (assuming of course single threaded sequential access but `List<T>` is not thread-safe anyways so it's a safe assumption :-)).

Comment: Hmmm... ok so my bug must be somewhere else. When the foreach runs, the new list already has a count greater than 0 though. I'll go back and look at it more carefully.

Comment: Yes. I was in error. The bug is located in a different method.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor:

```
List<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes = new List<Stream2FieldTypes>(0);
```

will create a list with a default capacity of zero.

**ETA**: Though, looking at Reflector, it seems that the static and default constructors *also* create the list with a default capacity of zero.  So your code as it stands should create a list with no elements and no reserved capacity.  Should be more performant than the explicit constructor.

Comment: I don't know if I want the default capacity to be zero. That sounds like I wouldn't be able to add items in the future.

Comment: You will always be able to add items in the future.  Capacity is not an upper limit and the list will grow by factors of 2 when you reach capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use IEnumerable, you can do some nice tricks:

```
public void processTheList(List<string> someList = null)
{
    // Instead of special-casing null, make your code cleaner
    var list = someList ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    // Now we can always assume list is a valid IEnumerable
    foreach(string item in list) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a multi-threading issue, are you sure that this is a thread safe method and another thread didn't already add an item to this list?

We need to see this method in a bigger context of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have your constructor set up incorrectly.  I may be wrong but instead of `List<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes = new List<Stream2FieldTypes>();` you should be naming it different than the type you are using? `List<Stream2FieldTypes> SomethingElse = new List<Stream2FieldTypes>();`

Try that it should work.